# is it possible to open a report from c# program in edit/run mode

Tags: c#, report, builder

I wanna show my reports in reportviewer control in visual studio and open them in edit/run mode in report builder by clicking a button

I dont know how to open report builder from my program

I have a report server

thanks any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application?/Reports/ProductsReport");
```

where `Reports/ProductsReport` is the path to my report

see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobmeyers/archive/2006/01/24/517083.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then this is the answer:

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/8e0d8b0f-b1c2-44cc-9c52-9f9c1b82281e/
>
> The best way to embed an SSRS 2008 R2 report into a form is to deploy
>   the report to the report server and then use the Remote execution mode
>   in the Report Viewer control.  The RDLC format used with local
>   execution mode doesn't yet support the newer RDL specifcation that is
>   created with Report Builder 3.0.

Comment: thanks for answering but I only want to give the user the ability to **edit** server reports in report builder program so I need to open report builder from C# by clicking a button.